# Interfacing a piezoelectric pressure sensor with a microcontroller

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, pressure, piezoelectric-effect

I'm working on monitoring injection molding process pressure inside the mold. The pressure range is expected to be between 1500 - 3000 bar. The mold temperature is expected to be around 100C while the melt (plastic) temperature can go up to 300C. While looking for sensors that can operate under these conditions I found piezoelectric pressure sensors like [this one](https://www.baumer.com/medias/__secure__/en_DAB_DPPC_DS02.5.pdf?mediaPK=8949107589150) that can operate under these conditions.

However, since these sensors are piezoelectric, I understand they require a charge amplifier to convert the small amount of charge output from the sensor into a voltage that is readable by a microcontroller. I found a charge amplifier like [this one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/amphenol-wilcoxon-sensing-technologies/CC701/13148575) on digikey though it is not stocked. These charge amplifiers seem extremely expensive. Would using these expensive charge amplifiers be the only way to read a piezoelectric pressure sensor? Would designing a charge amplifier circuit using op-amps be a feasible option?

I have looked at some piezoelectric pressure sensors which have an inbuilt charge amplifier circuit, but since they have the electronics in them their operating temperature drops below the requirement.

It would help a lot if someone could guide me down the right path or point me to some resources I could look at. Are piezoelectric pressure sensors the right choice for injection molding applications or am I looking at the wrong type of sensors?

Comment: They are difficult to design if they are to work well. The expense of buying them is pretty cheap in the long run.

Comment: Ah okay, that's what I expected as well. Are you aware of different types of pressure transducers that might work under the operating conditions mentioned? What do you think about something like a thin-film strain gauge sensor?

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/7520302_Design_of_ultrasonic_transmitters_with_defined_frequency_characteristics_for_wireless_pressure_sensing_in_injection_molding